# Unity C# Player going too fast with Rigidbody2D.AddForce

Tags: c#, vector, 2d, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a game in **Unity 5**. It's a **2D game** and I want my character to automatically go forward. But my problem is that since I use **Rigidbody2D.AddForce**, it keeps adding force every frame and I don't want that. I want my **speed** to be at *5.0f*, not more or less. Is there a way to set a limit or keep a constant speed?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody2D player;

public bool grounded = false;
private bool hasJumped = false;

public float movementspeed = 5.0f;
public float jumpforce = 450.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    player.AddForce(transform.right * movementspeed);

    // (JumpScript)
}

void FixedUpdate(){

    // (JumpScript)

}
}
```

Comment: the answer is (1) you must use real units, 1 meter in unity is "really" 1 meter, one kilogram in unity is really one kilogram (2) it's impossible to be a physics game programmer unless you ................... are incredibly expert ***at physics***.  Just think about it.  imagine you said to someone "well i'm going to *program physics*".  of course they'd assume you are an expert in physics, mechanical engineering, etc.

Comment: @Icevx1 you may want to watch some unity's tutorials [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am very suprised at the answers here, they are way off. Your problem is that you are adding force in the update, which is called every frame. That means that every frame of the game the object will gain 5 more force and speed up infinitely.

If you want the object to get 5 force and then stay at that speed, just put the add force in the start instead of the update. Like this:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    player = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    player.AddForce(transform.right * movementspeed);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    // (JumpScript)
}
```

Comment: @Icevx1 As a new user please remember to "tick" an answer as accepted if it was useful and resolved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The problem in your code is that the object will accelerate for 1 frame then stop. I want it to move every frame with a fixed speed.

Comment: The code I have provided would make the item recieve an added force in only one frame, but that force would remain aftwards and the item will continue to move with that force until something stops it.


You could think of it like pushing an ice skater. You only push him once, and he will glide out with the force of that push until stopped. 


If that is not the result you are trying to achieve let me know and I can try to help you do it the way you want.

Comment: Ah... Your code does work, I apologise! The thing that was wrong was when my object (cube) touched the ground it stopped. I fixed it by using the PhysicsMaterial2D (something like that) and unchecked friction! I'll be switching to sprites very soon, just wanted to get the basic mechanics down.

Comment: Ah I see. Well good to know you got it working. Remember to tick the answer as accepted to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the Rigidbody.velocity to 5.

However, sooner or later knowing some physics will come very handy. The absolute minimum is knowing Newton's laws.

In your case, if you are absolutely dedicated to using `AddForce()` you could use `ForceMode.Impulse` as the 3rd parameter to give your object an instant push (instead of gradual acceleration). This way you would have to call `AddForce()` only once, not repeatedly. You can calculate the exact amount of force you need by the formula for Kinetic energy:

> Force = 0.5f * Mass * Velocity^2

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a 2D game like yours in unity too. And I use an `if` to check the velocity and use another variable for the force like this:

```
public float acel = 50, speed = 5;
Rigidbody2D rbody;
void FixedUpdate () {
    // As you want to move right, we don't have to calculate the absolute value
    if (rbody.velocity.x < speed)
        rbody.AddForce(Vector2.right*acel);
}
```

The speed won't always be 5 but maybe that isn't important though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Physics to move your player at a constant speed then you need to apply force at the beginning until the speed you want is reached, only then change force to 0. In order for this to work as expected I would also add a [Physic Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) to the collider of the character to make sure that no friction is slowing down the character.

P.S: If you are creating some sort of infinite runner game I would consider moving and reusing the environment rather than the player.